# Bash negative exponention arithmetic expansion

Tags: bash

Trying to do

```
1*2^-2
```

tried code

```
echo "$((1 * (1/2**2)))" == 0
printf %.3f "$((1 * (1/2**2)))" == 0.000
also tried echo 1/2 | bc == 0
```

Problem seems that division operator is only not working maybe its a bug in cygwin
Executing code in cygwin bash
Help

Comment: `bash` arithmetic is integer only. `1/2` is equal to `0`, not `0.5`, in `bash` arithmetic.

Comment: even bc and expr not working

Comment: i have limited tools on remote cygwin environment and tried using bc calculator but it was also producing 0

Comment: Did you try with `bc -l`? What is the desired outcome?

Comment: `bc` is not related to `bash` and should work. Try `echo "1/2^2" | bc -l`

Comment: ok -l works also  echo "scale = 2; 1 * 2^-2" | bc works

Answer (score 1):

If `awk` is available:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print 1 * (1/2**2), 1* (1/2^2) }'
0.25 0.25

$ awk 'BEGIN { printf "%.3f / %.3f", 1 * (1/2**2), 1* (1/2^2) }'
0.250 / 0.250
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "scale = 2; 1 * 2^-2" | bc
```

Also bc -l option works as suggested in comment

Comment: Yes, `bc -l` sets the scale to a default non-zero value (20 I believe): `echo scale | bc -l`